# Translates the XInput calls to DirectInput calls on MAC OS X (Emulate x360 controller from PS3 one)

Tags: macos, controller, directinput, playstation3, xinput

There are a lot of games in steam working with x360 controllers but not mapped properly with a PS3 DS3 controller...

MotionInJoy do it clean with "emulate 360 controller" but it works only on PC.
There is another PC-only project : x360ce : https://code.google.com/p/x360ce/

Here is the question : is there any solution for mac os x ?
If not, why !?

Comment: Controllers are primarily output-only. That is, they mostly send signals: I pressed this button, have this axis pushed this much, etc. So I think (not sure) that the controller is sending DirectInput and most steam games want to receive XInput. All this to say maybe rephrase as "Translates DI calls to XI"?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a solution on OSX that reads DirectInput and emulates XInput.

I took a look at x360ce. It uses [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/wiki/class-library-api/directinput/) to communicate on both DirectInput and Xinput APIs, so it'd be a great start for an app like this. Problem is it's written in C#. This is why there is no solution in OSX--the best library for interfacing with DI/XI is written (naturally) in a Microsoft language.

I think we'd need something like [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/osx/) to run .cs on mac, I'm not sure.

Not a small project to either write a native interface to DI/XI or run SharpDX on a mac, but it'd be pretty educational.